# how to get xml text selected in my java code [android]

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

In this when I long press on any of the prof names a context menu pops up
which further ask to choose one of the options(for better understanding pls check below)

I have a resc.xml file in which details of prof email, office hours and phone number are mentioned. What I am trying to do is when someone clicks on any of the three options in the context menu, it should display a toast giving that particular professor office hour details or email id whatever was clicked in context menu.

For Eg if someone long press on 'Dr David Hicks' name context menu will pop up
and then if I click on 'Email id' it should display a toast of Dr david hicks email address from resc.xml file.

Note: the list view of the main page where all the names of all the professors 
are being displayed is being picked up from another xml file 'item_data.xml'

Can somebody pls help me with this!

```
MainActivity.java

package com.example.tamukcompscfaculty;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

        private String[] Professors;
        String na;
        int position;

        int position2;
        String ss;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                 Professors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Professors);
                ArrayAdapter<String> ProgAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Professors);
                setListAdapter(ProgAdapter);
                registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                if(v==getListView()){

                        MenuInflater menuInflater=getMenuInflater();
                        menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.More);
                        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.details, menu);

                        //get the position of row clicked
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
                position = info.position;
                        ss = Professors[position].toString(); // String ss is holding name of professor


                }
                super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem args) {
                na = args.toString(); // na is holding string value of the item clicked in context menu



                return super.onContextItemSelected(args);
        }


}

Strings.XML

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

        <string name="app_name">TamukCompScFaculty</string>
        <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
        <string name="FacultyText"><u>Faculty Office Hours Details</u></string>
        <string name="Office_Hours">Check Office Hours</string>
        <string name="Email">Email Id</string>
        <string name="Phonenumber">Phone Number</string>
        <string name="More"><u>Click below to check the details</u></string>
        <string name="title_activity_start">StartActivity</string>

    </resources>


resc.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string-array name = "resc">

            <item>Dr. David Hicks
                             <Email>david@tamuk.com</Email>
                             <Phonenumber>512-000-0000</Phonenumber>
                             <Office_Hours>Mon to fri 9am to 1pm</Office_Hours>
                 </item>

                 <item >Dr. Mohammad S. Khan
                                      <Email>khan@tamuk.com</Email>
                             <Phonenumber>512-111-1111</Phonenumber>
                             <Office_Hours>Mon to fri 9am to 1pm</Office_Hours>
                 </item>

                 <item >Dr. Young Lee
                           <Email>lee@tamuk.com</Email>
                             <Phonenumber>512-222-1111</Phonenumber>
                             <Office_Hours>Mon to fri 9am to 1pm</Office_Hours>
                 </item>

                 <item >Dr. Mais Nijim
                          <Email>Nijim@tamuk.com</Email>
                             <Phonenumber>512-333-1111</Phonenumber>
                             <Office_Hours>Mon to fri 9am to 1pm</Office_Hours>
                 </item>

                 <item >Dr. Ashraf Yaseen
                          <Email>Yaseen@tamuk.com</Email>
                             <Phonenumber>512-444-1111</Phonenumber>
                             <Office_Hours>Mon to fri 9am to 1pm</Office_Hours>
                 </item>

                <item >Ms. Jeong Yang
                               <Email>Yang@tamuk.com</Email>
                             <Phonenumber>512-555-1111</Phonenumber>
                             <Office_Hours>Mon to fri 9am to 1pm</Office_Hours>
                 </item>

                <item >Dr. Abdelrahman Elleithy
                               <Email>Elleithy@tamuk.com</Email>
                             <Phonenumber>512-666-1111</Phonenumber>
                             <Office_Hours>Mon to fri 9am to 1pm</Office_Hours>
                 </item>

                <item >Dr. Wei-Da Hao
                               <Email>Hao@tamuk.com</Email>
                             <Phonenumber>512-777-1111</Phonenumber>
                             <Office_Hours>Mon to fri 9am to 1pm</Office_Hours>
                 </item>

                <item >Dr. Syed Iqbal Omar
                              <Email>Omar@tamuk.com</Email>
                             <Phonenumber>512-888-1111</Phonenumber>
                             <Office_Hours>Mon to fri 9am to 1pm</Office_Hours>
                 </item>

                <item >Dr. Muhammad Aurangzeb
                              <Email>Aurangzeb@tamuk.com</Email>
                             <Phonenumber>512-999-1111</Phonenumber>
                             <Office_Hours>Mon to fri 9am to 1pm</Office_Hours>
                 </item>

                <item >Dr. Gahangir Hossain
                               <Email>Hossain@tamuk.com</Email>
                             <Phonenumber>512-111-4444</Phonenumber>
                             <Office_Hours>Mon to fri 9am to 1pm</Office_Hours>
                 </item>

        </string-array> 
    </resources>

item_data.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string-array name = "Professors">

                <item >Dr. David Hicks</item>
                   <item >Dr. Mohammad S. Khan</item>
            <item >Dr. Young Lee</item>
            <item >Dr. Mais Nijim</item>
            <item >Dr. Ashraf Yaseen</item>
                <item >Ms. Jeong Yang</item>
                <item >Dr. Abdelrahman Elleithy</item>
                <item >Dr. Wei-Da Hao</item>
                <item >Dr. Syed Iqbal Omar</item>
                <item >Dr. Muhammad Aurangzeb</item>
                <item >Dr. Gahangir Hossain</item>


        </string-array>    

    </resources>

activity_main.xml

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.tamukcompscfaculty.MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profs"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:text="@string/FacultyText"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp" >

        </ListView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/engineering" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: SnapShot1]

[image: SnapShot2]

Comment: In case any other detail is needed pls let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take emails as an example. Define the string xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name = "Professors">
        <item >Dr. David Hicks</item>
        <item >Dr. Mohammad S. Khan</item>
        <item >Dr. Young Lee</item>
        <item >Dr. Mais Nijim</item>
        <item >Dr. Ashraf Yaseen</item>
        <item >Ms. Jeong Yang</item>
        <item >Dr. Abdelrahman Elleithy</item>
        <item >Dr. Wei-Da Hao</item>
        <item >Dr. Syed Iqbal Omar</item>
        <item >Dr. Muhammad Aurangzeb</item>
        <item >Dr. Gahangir Hossain</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name = "Emails">
        <item >david@tamuk.com</item>
        <item >khan@tamuk.com</item>
        <item >lee@tamuk.com</item>
        <item >Nijim@tamuk.com</item>
        <item >Yaseen@tamuk.com</item>
        <item >Yang@tamuk.com</item>
        <item >Elleithy@tamuk.com</item>
        <item >Hao@tamuk.com</item>
        <item >Omar@tamuk.com</item>
        <item >Aurangzeb@tamuk.com</item>
        <item >Hossain@tamuk.com</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

In your JAVA code,

```
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.email:
                    String email = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Emails)[position];
                    break;
                case R.id.phone_number:
                    break;
                case R.id.office_hours:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
    }
```

R.id.email, R.id.phone_number, R.id.office_hours are the ids you assigned in R.menu.details

Comment: pls check resc.xml I want to pull infomation from that xml file.For eg  if I long press on 'Dr David Hicks' name context menu will pop up and then if I click on 'Email id' it should display a toast of Dr david hicks email address from resc.xml file.I am wanting to know how can we do this.

Comment: I see. I would put all these into a json file and put the file under res/raw folder, and then parse the file into your own data model so you can do whatever you want. But if you have to use xml, just like your Professors array, you can define 3 more arrays which is emails, phoneNumbers and officeHours, with menuItem id you know which array to look for, and with position you know which item in the array to get.

Comment: I would like to go with the xml file and will try to implement what you mentioned.Will let you know if I am able to pull it off!

Comment: hey can you pls help with this I am not able to implement what you mentioned